# How much storage space is required to play Grand Theft Auto 5 on the Xbox 360?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I just got it, it said there wasn't enough storage and I erased almost everything, but apparently my storage is full and I can't play it. Help?

Comment: How much space do you have?

Comment: "I erased almost everything" tells us nothing. How much did you have to start with? How much did you end up with after the cleanup? Without any concrete numbers, this would just be a guessing game.

Answer (score 2):

You will need more than 8 GB available on your Xbox 360/PlayStation 3. If you do not have this much available space you will need to delete some things or configure an external hard drive or usb with a capacity greater than 8 GB. Note that configuring a USB/Hard Drive will clear everything on it so make sure to create a backup :P

Comment: I've heard that the multiplayer mode in GTA 5 is a download-able addon, which takes up even more space. Do you know how much?